# save data for offline mode of a web service app

Tags: android, sqlite, offline, offline-mode

I have developed an android tourist app using **web service (json api)**,the app is working fine. App have map view with markers ,and photo gallery ,location detail etc.
Now client want to add a feature of **offline mode** ,means that when the app will work perfectly when internet will not available.

I have google a lot and found that sqlite database will be very useful for this functionality and I can implement this but my problem is that :

->how to save data in sqlite,as there are 15-20 apis which I had implemented in the app

->now how will I save these apis to the sqlite table and how to connect them in offline mode with the app

->how will connect all the tables each other

I have never done this kind of work ,please suggest me any help.

Please suggest me any solution,If you have another way to implement this functionality then please guide me .

Comment: You can use http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: thanks for response But I am not asking for how to implement external db ,I am asking to suggest how to manage the large db to convert 15-20 apis to db tables

Comment: You manage the DB like any other DB. What exactly is the problem?